# Why doesn't Awesome Print work on some Rails collection objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-console, awesomeprint

Awesome Print generally works perfectly for me in Rails.

But when doing `ap Post.all` in the Rails console I only get the standard full line output.

Has it to do with the returned `ActiveRecord_Relation` class or something else, because when an array is returned, like in `ap Post.all.each {|p| p}`, Awesome Print does it's job.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not just convert it to array?

```
ap Post.all.to_a
```

<strike>or you can create a patch:</strike>

```
alias :old_ap :ap
def ap(object, option={})
  if object.class == ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Post
    old_ap object.to_a, option
  else
    old_ap object, option
  end
end
```

---

You are right. Maybe it's an incompatible problem with Rails4 as the last commit on github is 6 months ago. Here is the problem:

***awesome_print-1.2.0/lib/awesome_print/ext/active_record.rb@24***

```
def cast_with_active_record(object, type)
  cast = cast_without_active_record(object, type)
  return cast if !defined?(::ActiveRecord)

  if object.is_a?(::ActiveRecord::Base)
    cast = :active_record_instance
  elsif object.is_a?(Class) && object.ancestors.include?(::ActiveRecord::Base)
    cast = :active_record_class
  elsif type == :activerecord_relation #HERE the problem
    cast = :array
  end
  cast
end
```

the method will set the cast to array when the `type` is `:activerecord_relation`

while in ***awesome_print-1.2.0/lib/awesome_print/inspector.rb@151***

```
def printable(object)
  case object
  when Array  then :array
  when Hash   then :hash
  when File   then :file
  when Dir    then :dir
  when Struct then :struct
  else object.class.to_s.gsub(/:+/, "_").downcase.to_sym #HERE gets the type
  end
end
```

But the class of Relation object in rails4 is like:

> > Post.all.class 
>   => ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Post

So the condition in `cast_with_active_record` gets a type "activerecord_relation_activerecord_relation_post" rather than "activerecord_relation". Then the condition is failed, and no cast done.

Here's a new patch that may work:

```
module AwesomePrint
  class Inspector
    alias_method :old_printable, :printable
    private
    def printable(object)
      if object.class.to_s.downcase.include?("activerecord_relation")
        return :activerecord_relation
      end
      old_printable(object)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: That's true, but I'm curious as well if it is a `Relation` class problem (I've just guessed that it's the cause) and if so, why?

Comment: Thanks for the very educative answer!

Comment: Did you created a Pull Request?

Comment: @ArnoldRoa the latest version of awesome_print(1.7.0) has already fixed this issue. You can use `bundle update awesome_print` to update

Answer (score 0):

What I am doing is putting this in your `~/.pryrc`

```
class Class
  def list_all
    self.all.each { |s| puts s }
  end
end
```